# Geolocation works for some users, but not for others?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

what are some reasons geolocation may not work? My code is very simple:

```
if navigator.geolocation
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (position) ->
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
      map.setCenter pos
      map.setZoom(13)
      console.log position
```

On button click, it runs that code. If they accept, it takes the location, moves the map there.

Right now it's working for some of my users, but not for my others. Its very hard to debug since it's not restricted to my laptop. What are some reasons this could be happening? Are there better ways of geolocating?

Comment: there is nothing to debug, that's how it is: geolocation may fail

Comment: connect your laptop via ethernet instead of wifi, maybe you'll get different results